# Strange rep cap behavior: how did I get 201 for the day?

Tags: support, reputation

How did I manage to get 201 points for the day just ended?  The Rep panel just shows the last upvote with +1 after a long string of blanks since I had already reached the limit of 200.

I *have* noticed that the capping system is annoyingly dumb: after truncating incoming upvotes, if I “spend” points like with a downvote it really does take it off leaving 199 rather tha  re-evaluating the truncation of incoming votes.

Now I recall accidently touching a downvote and immediatly reversing that (when trying to scroll on the tablet), so maybe it’s an outright bug in capping with downvote/undownvote, or maybe someone upvoted me at the same moment so it awarded the 1 point (instead of 10) to bring it back to 200, but then the undownvote *returned the point*.  If that’s true, although lesser of an actual bug, it would allow funny ways to bypass the cap.

Answer (score 5):

Did you downvote an answer?  Was that answer then deleted?

I've seen things get funny around the edges of the rep cap.  If you downvote (taking you to 199 for the day) and somebody then upvotes one of your posts, you'll get +1.  If the post you downvoted then gets deleted you'll get your +1 back, but that +1 doesn't count against the rep cap so you get it even though you're already at 200.

Other things that don't count against the rep cap: answer acceptances and bounties.

Comment: Imagine the frustration if you are awarded a +500 bounty and it gets capped at 200 minus whatever upvotes you already had for the day!

Comment: @MichaelKjörling exactly.  They would have to make an exception for bigger bounties anyway, and that raises the question of acceptances, and I suppose also edits for those who don't have the privilege yet.  I think the rule is that you're capped at 200 from votes, period.

Comment: I think edits also count toward the daily rep cap, and should. Either way, your theory on how one could get to 201 in a day sounds plausible.